# Delete set of files using find command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

## Background

Delete a set of files, scattered across different directories.

## Problem

The following code does not work (the unescaped `|` causes issues);

```
for %i in (dir /s/b | find "lock") do echo del %i
```

## Question

Without writing a batch file, how would you delete all files named "lock" (i.e., found using the `find` command) within the current directory and all subdirectories (including hidden directories)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code needs a few touchups.  The pipe operator needs to be escaped by the batch escape character `^` and when using quotations within the parentheses for a command, the `usebackq` option must be specified.

[`for /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Batch Format:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /s /b ^| find "lock"`) do echo %%i
```

Command Line Format:

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`dir /s /b ^| find "lock"`) do echo %i
```

Replace `echo` with `del` and any of its options when you want it to actually delete the files. Note the double percent signs are needed when used within a bat file, single when used directly on the command line.

Another method is to use the `forfiles` command. [`forfiles /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=WS.10).aspx)

```
forfiles /m *lock* /s /c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

**Note**, both of these methods will also delete any folders that contain the search term `lock`.  Additional steps would be needed to be taken to prevent this.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Your welcome.

Comment: @DaveJarvis  You may also want to add the `/l` option to the `dir` command to cause a pure lowercase comparison, or add the `/i` option to the `find` command to cause a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 2):

For a given drive and/or path (looks in subfolders also):

```
del /f /s /q c:\windows\lock
```

Answer (score 1):

[david-ruhmann](https://superuser.com/a/520684/326186)  answer doesn't work with path containing spaces! You can use:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (`dir /s /b ^| find "lock"`) do del "%i"
```

If you have hinned files you can use:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (`dir /s /b /a ^| find "lock"`) do del "%i" /A:H
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to directly use the del command as follows:

```
del /s c:\directory\*_gdiplus*.*
```

where "_gdiplus", e.g., is the filename that contains the string you want to be deleted.

Comment: If you don't format your code properly it won't display all the characters. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.